# Screen doesn't update when I change a UILabel's text

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel, master-detail

My Environment is Xcode 6.3, target is iOS8.3 for iPad.
I'm learning the Master-Detail view by using Xcode's template. Some strange problem appears when I try to set a label's text in the detail view:
 If I put the statement which changes the label's text in P1 position, it works.

But if I put the statement in P2 position, it doesn't work.

Under both circumstances, the detailDescriptionLabel.text was changed, but only the P1 statement actually update the screen.(I have checked that function configureView() was called both times)

Can anybody helps me? Thanks a lot.

Below are my code snippets:

MasterController.m:

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *objects;

@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PresidentList" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *presidentInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[presidentInfo objectForKey:@"presidents"]];

    self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Segues

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
        controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
        controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;

        //P1
        //controller.detailItem = (self.objects[indexPath.row])[@"url"];
    }
}



#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.objects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = (self.objects[indexPath.row])[@"name"];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //P2
    //self.detailViewController.detailItem = (self.objects[indexPath.row])[@"url"];
}
@end
```

DetailController.m:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *masterPopoverController;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem {
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;
        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
    if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) {
        [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)configureView {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = self.detailItem;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Split view

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc {
    barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = pc;
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = nil;
}
@end
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is. You proved, quite rightly, that position P1 is right and position P2 is wrong. - You might try logging `self.detailViewController` in position P2, to learn even more...

Comment: In fact, the detailViewController is quite simple, I've put the whole file here. I just cannot find anything extraordinary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using segues and that's the point of using the dedicated function (`prepareForSegue`) designated appositely to initialize values AFTER the view destination view has been anyway created.

Unless you instantiate and show the view by yourself in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` there is no point in setting something to such a viewcontroller.

Comment: Yes you are right. I'm just wondering if a UILabel's text changed, shouldn't the view also updated?

Comment: @ZhuShengqi Only if the view, the uilabel to the main event loop hierarchy. The problem here is that you already have a view controller automatically generated by the segue, but in the P2 position you are creating a second view controller, whose is never show, and you are modifying that instead of the shown one.

Comment: I see your point, thanks a lot. I should study the mechanisms provided by Apple more :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that self.detailViewController is nil. Hence P2 will not work.

Difficult to say without seeing all the code but in prepareForSegue, you might want to assign it there.

Comment: I've checked it's not nil. Maybe putting the initializing code in prepareForSegue() is a good idea, I'm just curious what's the difference in P1 and P2 :)